# Google drive sdk convert uploaded document

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to convert an uploaded .doc to Google Doc format within a PHP web application- so that I can then export it again in a variety of other formats.

I have this...

```
$result = $service->files->create($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => 'application/msword',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart'

));
```

But sadly the new API (v3) doesn't support the 'conver=true' parameter...and the docs say "Provide the target mimeType in the resource body"

If I change `mimeType` to `=> 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'` I get a 400 error...`Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content`.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's [error 400](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request), it could mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

Check if you're converting your file to currently supported conversions. See [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19) to learn more.

Try using this sample code:

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'My Report',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'));
$content = file_get_contents('files/report.csv');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```